# Profiling MapReduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using an oozie workflow to kick off multiple mapreduce jobs on a distributed cluster on CDH5.

Wondering if anyone can suggest any profilers. I was looking at HPROF and jumbune.  any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use the builtin counters to time critical sections:

```
long start = Time.now();
codeToTime();
long timeElapsed = Time.now() - start;
reporter.incrCounter("performance", "codeWeTimed", timeElapsed);
```